# Symfony2 routing annotation leads to NotFoundHttpException 1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, routes

I get the following exception when trying to access `//localhost/dga/web/app_dev.php/gerer/sami`.

> No route found for "GET /gerer/sami" 404 Not Found -
>   NotFoundHttpException 1 linked Exception:
>
> ```
> ResourceNotFoundException »
> ```

**src/app/config/routing.yml**

```
gestion_utilisateur:
    resource: "@GestionUtilisateurBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

**src/Application/EncaissementBundle/Controller/GererController.php**

```
namespace Application\EncaissementBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/gerer/{name}", name="application_encaissement_gere")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name) 
    {
        return $this->render(
            'ApplicationEncaissementBundle:Gerer:index.html.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        );
     }
```

Comment: DefaultController in GererController.php?

Comment: The filename and class-name not matching should be the cause for this problem as @AhmedSiouani pointed out correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, the action `indexAction` you defined is in the controller `DefaultController`. But the response you are send is to the a twig file of another controler which shall be `GererController`.

Make some checks on the controllers name & the twig resource you are calling (which is `'ApplicationEncaissementBundle:Gerer:index.html.twig'`).

How many controllers you have?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

it works!!I just configured my apache server

> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

And to comment this ***/home/user/NetBeansProjects*** in the file apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
#<Directory /home/user/NetBeansProjects>
#  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#  AllowOverride All
#  Order allow,deny
#  Allow from all
#</Directory>
```

:) amine thank you for your help